# TYPO3 login error: non-static method should not be called statically

Tags: php, static, typo3, non-static

I have an error occuring when trying to login to my TYPO3 backend. Unfortunately I dont know much php and dont know how to fix it...

This is the error:

> PHP Runtime Notice: call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, non-static method
>   Tx_Extbase_Utility_Extension::configureModule() should not be called
>   statically in /www/htdocs/w00754c9/t3lib/class.t3lib_loadmodules.php
>   line 228

And this is the code of class.t3lib_loadmodules.php, from line 219 on:

```
function checkMod($name, $fullpath) {
    if ($name == 'user_ws' && !t3lib_extMgm::isLoaded('version')) {
        return FALSE;
    }

        // Check for own way of configuring module
    if (is_array($GLOBALS['TBE_MODULES']['_configuration'][$name]['configureModuleFunction'])) {
        $obj = $GLOBALS['TBE_MODULES']['_configuration'][$name]['configureModuleFunction'];
        if (is_callable($obj)) {
            $MCONF = call_user_func($obj, $name, $fullpath);
            if ($this->checkModAccess($name, $MCONF) !== TRUE) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            return $MCONF;
        }
    }
```

Line 228 is this one : `$MCONF = call_user_func($obj, $name, $fullpath);`

Can anyone help please?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

It seems you use an newer PHP Version than TYPO3 needed. So it comes to errors.

You have two options: you can update your TYPO3 instance or supress the strict error message.

The second can be reached by adding `^ E_STRICT` to your php error reporting var in your webserver or in the TYPO3 install tool.

I personaly recommend option one ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much! But updating the Typo3 instance is a big project I fear.. So maybe for the moment I just add ^ E_STRICT to my error reporting var.

Comment: Regards option 1: How can I update my TYPO3 instance without being able to login? And also, without destroying the whole website? I'm currently using Typo 4.6, its an older website

Comment: An Update from 4.6 is not possible without some downtime. I recommend to duplicate the installation in an other web space and try how the update. Affected. But I think this should be an separate question or search for how to's.

Comment: Okay, now I added E_STRICT, but it changed nothing. then I replaced it with NULL to turn off error reporting, but still the error is displayed...